# Bad File Descriptor on a serial port

Tags: c, serial-port, file-descriptor

I'm implementing a simple protocol to do file transfer between 2 PC's over serial port and I'm getting a weird error.

On the main I call a function "llopen":

```c
int 
llopen(int port, int type) {

    int     fd = 0;
    char*   PORT;


    PORT = malloc( sizeof(char) * (strlen(COM) + 1) );
    sprintf(PORT,"%s%d",COM,port);

    fd = initialization(PORT); // Open(...): returns a file descriptor!

    switch(type) {
            case SENDER:
                    return connectSender(fd);
                    break;
            case RECEIVER:
                    return connectReceiver(fd);
                    break;
    }

    return fd; // The fd value here is 5

}
```

After that, I call a function *llwrite(int fd, ...)* to write a string to the file descriptor, but I'm getting an error: "Bad file descriptor" on *llwrite(int fd, ...)*. If I call again the *initialization(port)* function, before that, it works and it writes the N bytes on the file descriptor, but if I don't it gives to me the "Bad file descriptor" error again.

Here it is the *llwrite(int fd, ...)* function:

```c
int 
llwrite(int fileDescriptor, unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int length) {


    // The fd value here is 5
    return writeBuffer(fileDescriptor,buffer,length);

}
```

Even before the *return* statement if I call, for instance, the *tcflush(...)* function I'm getting the "Bad file descriptor" error.

Any clue? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The problem is solved.

*llopen(...)* was wrong. I was returning the number of bytes wrote on the *ConnectReceiver(...)* / *ConnectSender(...)* and not the *file descriptor*

Now it's right:

```c
int 
llopen(int port, int type) {

   int     fd = 0;
   char*   PORT;


   PORT = malloc( sizeof(char) * (strlen(COM) + 1) );
   sprintf(PORT,"%s%d",COM,port);

   fd = initialization(PORT); // Open(...): returns a file descriptor!

   switch(type) {
           case SENDER:
                   if( connectSender(fd) > 0 ) return fd;
           case RECEIVER:
                   if( connectReceiver(fd) > 0 ) return fd;
   }

   return -1;

}
```

Comment: You don't allocate enough bytes for PORT, it should be at least +2 to have enough space for the port number.  This is otherwise a seemingly strange mix of *nix and Windows code.

Comment: note that this only permits the use of port COM1 to COM9, and may fail with some usb/serial converters. you should really open `\\.\COM1` (beware of escaping the backslashes properly...)

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, you're right. But the problem is not that. I mean, I can execute _ConnectSender(...)_ and _ConnectReceiver(...)_ and I'm getting the correct file descriptor, but then I'm trying to execute  _llwrite(int fd)_ and it's not working.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson It is irrelevant on the case.

Comment: Well, you know you are corrupting the heap and then wonder why the program isn't working correctly.  Stop corrupting the heap first.  Use a debugger if that doesn't help.

Comment: @joaoqalves: indeed, that's why i posted this as a comment and not as an answer. that kind of mistake will hit sooner or later, and you will wonder why it does not work for ages. you have been warned...

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information here, but it's worth a shot noting that you do

```
return connectSender(fd);
break;
```

The break there is dead code, since the return stops execution of the function. Perhaps you didn't mean to return?

If that's not the case try using `strace` to get more details about what's going on. If you're not on linux other OSes should have similar tools, such as `dtruss` or `ktrace`.

Comment: You're right. It's dead code and I meant to _return_ right there, but it's not relevant on the problem.